# Is there a method to invoke xQuery function from a textlist using saxon?

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon, xquery-3.0, oracle-osm

I have the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SpecializedActions>
        <SpecializedAction>
            <Name>ActivateAAA_Account</Name>
            <Function>holaaalib:activate($csmHeader, $component, $taskName, $osmOrderId)</Function>
        </SpecializedAction>
        <SpecializedAction>
            <Name>ActivateIMSAccount</Name>
            <Function>imsLib:activate($csmHeader, $component, $taskName, $osmOrderId)</Function>
        </SpecializedAction>
    </SpecializedActions>
```

and i tried to invoke the functions in my generic xQuery like this

```
if (fn:exists($specializedAList/SpecializedAction[Name/text() = $specializedActionName])) then
    $specializedAList/SpecializedAction[Name/text() = $specializedActionName]/Function/text()
```

but that way it will return a text *'imsLib:activate($csmHeader, $component, $taskName, $osmOrderId)'*. Is there a method to cast it as an xQuery expression?

Comment: Which version, which edition of Saxon is that? And is that all done with XQuery, or why is there a tag for XSLT as well?

Comment: And where does Oracle fit in? Is there a reason you chose those tags but omitted the Saxon tag?

Comment: Xquery 1.0, Saxon EE 9.8.0.12 Yes it's all done with XQuery. XSLT was a mistake. Oracle fits in because it's about Oracle's Order and Service Management

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 3.0 has an instruction `xsl:evaluate` which can be used to evaluate an XPath expression read from a source document (or conjured up at run-time in some other way). There's no standard equivalent in XQuery (though in principle you could do it using `fn:transform()` which dynamically invokes an XSLT transformation.

Saxon-PE and higher have an extension `saxon:evaluate()` which does much the same thing, and can be invoked from XQuery.